# SQL Server filter query results to only include the item with the latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which returns multiple results for an item. I only want to get 1 item with the latest date(most recent). I am currently getting results with every date where there is an entry.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [a].[Name]
  , [a].[IsGhostConvey]
  , [b].[AttorneyName]
  , [b].[IsGhostConveyAttorney]
  , [c].[InstitutionID]
  , [f].[Base_CreatedDate] AS 'DateLatestAccountOpened'
FROM 
    [Intermediary] [a]
INNER JOIN 
    [Attorney] [b] ON [a].[Name] = [b].[AttorneyName]
INNER JOIN 
    [IntermediaryInstitution] [c] ON [c].[IntermediaryID] = [a].[ID]
INNER JOIN  
    [IntermediaryBranch] [d] ON [d].[IntermediaryID] = [a].[Id]
INNER JOIN 
    [Matter] [e] ON [e].[BranchID] = [d].[Id]
INNER JOIN 
    [Account] [f] ON [f].[MatterID] = [e].[ID]
ORDER BY 
    [a].[Name], [f].[Base_CreatedDate] DESC;
```

I think I am missing a `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` statement.

My result is as follows:

```
Name    IsGhostConvey   AttorneyName    IsGhostConveyAttorney   InstitutionID   DateLatestAccountOpened
Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   2   2017-10-05 08:46:47.573
Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   2   2017-05-25 09:00:24.853
Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   2   2017-03-03 10:07:01.753
Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   2   2016-12-15 08:47:59.393
Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   2   2016-11-09 14:55:29.763
Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   2   2016-11-09 14:54:11.877
Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   2   2016-05-30 08:43:47.993
Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   2   NULL
Adriaan Booyens Attorneys   1   Adriaan Booyens Attorneys   1   1   2018-02-05 12:25:17.233
Adriaan Booyens Attorneys   1   Adriaan Booyens Attorneys   1   1   2017-06-14 10:25:42.687
```

But I would like this:

```
Name    IsGhostConvey   AttorneyName    IsGhostConveyAttorney   InstitutionID   DateLatestAccountOpened
Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   Adlam Attorneys - Benoni    1   2   2017-10-05 08:46:47.573
Adriaan Booyens Attorneys   1   Adriaan Booyens Attorneys   1   1   2018-02-05 12:25:17.233
```

Comment: You can just try changing ORDER BY f.Base_CreatedDate DESC, a.name.

Comment: This still returns unwanted results, just ordered differently

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for a complicated query like this:

```
with t as (
    SELECT a.Name, a.IsGhostConvey, b.AttorneyName, b.IsGhostConveyAttorney, c.InstitutionID, f.Base_CreatedDate AS 'DateLatestAccountOpened'
    FROM Intermediary a
    INNER JOIN Attorney b
    ON a.Name = b.AttorneyName
    INNER JOIN IntermediaryInstitution c
    ON c.IntermediaryID = a.ID
    INNER JOIN IntermediaryBranch d
    ON d.IntermediaryID = a.Id
    INNER JOIN Matter e
    ON e.BranchID = d.Id
    INNER JOIN Account f
    ON f.MatterID = e.ID
    )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
      row_number() over (partition by name order by DateLatestAccountOpened desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by Name, Base_CreatedDate DESC;
```

Comment: I get 'Incorrect Syntax near "DESC"' at row_number() over (partition by a.Name, f.Base_CreatedDate DESC) as seqnum. Removing the DESC gives me The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.

Comment: Just put "order by" before base_createddate inside the OVER clause. Looks like a syntax error when posting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
GROUP BY (name)
```

to get just 1 result for each name

Comment: LIMIT 1 is not valid in sql server. That is a mysql thing.

Comment: Would TOP work?